# Relationship between cyclotomic polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let $n, m$ be two natural numbers and $\Phi_n(q), \Phi_m(q)$ the $n$-th and $m$-th cyclotomic polynomials respectively. Define a function $c_{n,m} \colon \mathbb{N} \to \left\{0,1\right\}\cup \left\{ p \mid p \, \text{prime}\right\}$ by 
$$c_{m,n} =
\begin{cases}
0, \, & \text{if $n = m$}\\
p, \, & \text{if $\frac{n}{m} = p^j$ where $p$ prime and $j \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$}\\
1, \, & \text{if $\frac{n}{m}$ is not an integer power of a prime}
\end{cases}$$

> Show that $\Phi_m(q) \in \sqrt{\left( \Phi_n(q)\right) + (c_{m,n})[q]}$

This result should rely on properties of cyclotomic polynomials I am not aware of. Obviously if $c_{n,m} = 0$ the result is true since $n = m$ and $(c_{n,m}) = (0)$. If $c_{n,m} = 1$, then $(c_{m,n}) = (1) = \mathbb{Z}$, and then it is true that $\Phi_m(q) \in \sqrt{\left( \Phi_n(q)\right) +\mathbb{Z}[q]}$, correct?

Any answer or any reference to literature where this results or proven would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your notation is really unclear. Using the $\in$ symbol seems to indicate that you intend $\sqrt{\left( \Phi_n(q)\right) + (c_{m,n})[q]}$ to denote a set; what is the exact definition of this set?

Comment: @GregMartin The notation $\sqrt{(\Phi_n(q))+ (c_{m,n})[q]}$ means the radical of $(\Phi_n(q))+ (c_{m,n})[q]$. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you write, the statement in case $c_{m,n} = 1$ is immediate because clearly $\Phi_m(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x] = \mathbb{Z}[x] + (\Phi_n(x)) = \sqrt{\mathbb{Z}[x] + (\Phi_n(x))}$.  Since this is true for all $m,n$, the statement in this case is also not meaningful.

If $n = m p^i$ so that $c_{m,n} = p$, then we have $\Phi_n(x) = \Phi_m(x^{p^i})$ (elementary property of cyclotomic polynomials).

Therefore it suffices to prove that $$\Phi_m(x)^{p^i} \equiv \Phi_m(x^{p^i}) \mod p$$

But in fact this statement is more generally true of any polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.  It can be seen as an elaboration of the so-called "[Freshman's Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream)," that $(x+y)^{p} \equiv x^p + y^p \mod p$.   I also found a reference [here](https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/2015/Final%20Project%20-%20Porter,%20Brett.pdf) as lemma 4.3.  The first property I mentioned is theorem 3.2 there.

Comment: Thank you! The case where $c_{m,n} = 1$  is okay as I wrote on the question?

Comment: yep, i included a sentence about that.  Curious, does this exercise have some application?

Comment: Thank you, I've accepted your answer. And yes, though maybe not this part itself. I am trying to understand a paper about cyclotomic completions and this "obvious" result (as wrote by the author) wasn't so obvious to me at first...

Comment: Yes if I came across this in a paper I also would've appreciated a quick sentence for justification.